# Using previewCGImageRepresentation in both Xcode 13 and Xcode 12?

Tags: swift, ios15, xcode13

I’ve run into an issue where Xcode 13b2 (iOS 15 SDK) changed the Swift return type of `AVCapturePhoto.previewCGImageRepresentation()`. In Xcode 12.5.1 (iOS 14 SDK), this method returns `Unmanged<CGImage>`. In 13b2 - 13b4, it returns `CGImage?`.

I need my code to compile under both Xcode versions, since Xcode 13 has other issues, and can’t be used to submit builds to the App Store. I thought I was clever writing this, but it won’t compile, because it’s not conditional code compilation check but rather a runtime check:

```swift
extension AVCapturePhoto {
    func stupidOSChangePreviewCGImageRepresentation() -> CGImage? {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            return self.previewCGImageRepresentation()
        } else {
            return self.previewCGImageRepresentation()?.takeUnretainedValue()
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility might be to create a user-defined Xcode setting, but I don’t think that can be done conditionally based on Xcode or SDK version.

There might be some unsafe pointer histrionics one can do…

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a check on the swift compiler version. An exhaustive list is available on wikipedia at the time of writing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions

```
extension AVCapturePhoto {
    func stupidOSChangePreviewCGImageRepresentation() -> CGImage? {
    #if compiler(>=5.5)
        return self.previewCGImageRepresentation()
    #else
        return self.previewCGImageRepresentation()?.takeUnretainedValue()
    #endif
    }
}
```